# Allowing only usernames using "reasonable" characters

Tags: string

A username for a website can contain the space character, and yet it cannot be composed only of space characters. It can contain some symbols (like underscore and dash), but starting with certain symbols would look weird. Non-latin letters should be allowed, preferably for all languages, but tab and newline characters shouldn't. And definitely no Zalgo.

The rules composing what should and shouldn't be allowed in a reasonable naming system are complicated, however they are virtually the same for every website. Reimplementing them is probably a bad idea. Where can I find an implementation? I'm using PHP.

Comment: I'm upvoting this question because there probably should be a built-in function or external library that will do this for you.  It borderlines on shopping question, but it's not unreasonably so

Answer (score 0):

You should validate the username entered by the new user against a **regular expression** that run  a match against the allowed character set.

Example: The following allows only english alphanumeric characters and - and _.

```
function isNewUsernameValid ($name, $filter = "[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.]"){
    return preg_match("~" . $filter . "~iU", $name) ? false : true;
}

if ( !isNewUsernameValid ($name) ){
 print "Not a valid name.";
}
```

For your particular case, you'll have to come up with and test the regular expression.

Comment: I don't think this is a reasonable solution, as there is too much work involved. For example, manually allowing for characters from every language in the world and keeping that up to date.